# Add, remove, and append entries to an entries field via frontend form

Tags: form, entries-field, frontend

I'm making a one-button form, to add an entry to an entries field.
Adding seems pretty straightforward, but it overwrites any previous entry that occupied the entries field. How would I append an entry to the entries field, or remove an entry?

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ getCsrfInput() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
  <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{currentUrl}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="fields[tournamentTeams][]" value="{{team.id}}">

  <input type="submit" value="Add {{team.title}} to this Tournament">
</form>
```

My guess is, I will have to populate the entries field input value with the already-added entries to append the entry, and do the same kinda deal upon removing the entry- no idea how I would detect and remove the entry though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You guessed right, you have to set all already added entries again. To do this,
just have some Twig logic when outputting the fields:

```
{% for currentTeam in entry.tournamentTeams %}
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[tournamentTeams][]" value="{{ currentTeam.id }}">
{% endfor %}
<input type="hidden" name="fields[tournamentTeams][]" value="{{ team.id }}">
```

To remove the entry:

```
{% for currentTeam in entry.tournamentTeams if currentTeam.id != team.id %}
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[tournamentTeams][]" value="{{ currentTeam.id }}">
{% endfor %}
```

**Update:** What I'm not sure about is if the above code works when trying to remove the last remaining entry. If it doesn't work I'd try and add something like this:

```
{% if (entry.tournamentTeams|length == 1) and (entry.tournamentTeams.first().id == team.id) %}
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[tournamentTeams]" value="">
{% endif %}
```

---

Comment: so I didn't do my thorough testing with this... I did run into an issue with the last remaining entry. Unfortunately, your snippet does not work... Any other ideas?

Comment: ah! turns out it was the brackets suffix in the `name` attribute. It wasn't necessary. I updated the answer :)